# Attribute for Text Alignment?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, datagridview, attributes

I discovered the usefulness of Attributes in use with bindings.
For example the `[DisplayName]` Attribute to decorate properties to automatically get different columnheader names when they are bound to a datagridview.

Does there also exist an attribute for properties to propagate the alignment of the text in DataGridViewColumns?
I currently solved it by looping through the properties after binding and looking for the names I want to have right aligned. Seems like a rather ugly solution.

```
    myDataGridView.DataSource = myListOfRowObjects;

    //Datagrid Formatting
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn myCol in myDataGridView.Columns)
    {
        switch (myCol.DataPropertyName)
        {
            //Right Align Properties
            case "PropertyNameX":
            case "PropertyNameY":
                myCol.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
                break;

            //Left Align Properties pass here
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney I think, this is the whole point - nothing defined in design time. He uses attribs to bind and generate them in runtime

Comment: @GrantWinney exactly as T.S. mentioned - the object is bound at runtime and therefore the columns are created at that point.